# In vim, how can I replace recursively across multiple *.js files with :args and :argdo?

Tags: recursion, search, vim, replace

As the headline states: In vim, how can I replace recursively across multiple *.js files with :args and :argdo?

I've found this:

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2776/vim-search-replace-all-files-in-current-project-folder

where it says:

> For example, :args **/*.rb will recursively search the current directory for ruby files.

So I do a (remember: I'm trying to get all javascript files recursively)

:args **/*.js

But what's returned is only the *content* of the first javascript file which is being found in the directory. No other files are being shown, let alone a list of javascript files in the root and in the subfolders.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does :buffers say?

Comment: buffers does actually list them (i.e. the respective js-files) all.

Comment: So all you have to do now, is :argdo %s/search/replace/g  :bufdo also works instead of :argdo

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was confused, because I expected some list to be shown when invoking :args. Thanks for clearing my view.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running?

```
:args
```

Because at this point vim should be loaded all the `*.js` files into its arglist. If your arglist was populated you can do something like:

```
:silent argdo :%s/_params/params/ge | update
```

I would also recommend setting lazydraw `:set lazyredraw` just in case you are running macros because it stops giving feedback every time the macro runs.